# Questions about adages (Поговорка) and Proverbs (Пословица)

Tags: discussion

Are questions regarding adages (Поговорки) / proverbs (Пословицы) origins and meanings accepted on this site?

Answer (score 9):

I think they definitely should. The answers to this questions will be interesting for many people, and the answers are often not trivial.

Answer (score 4):

I think adages & proverbs are the core part of Russian language/mentality, so this is a definitely right place for them.